# dynamically populate select option in jsp using MVC

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

i have 5 files
--jsp page
--bean class
--servlet
--DAO class
--display servlet

I want to get ID and name form database and show it in jsp page
I am using JSTL to get select option
now i want to know where to get data from tables and how to send it to jsp page 
help me I am stuck

Comment: In your JSP : call your DAO service methods to get the data from the DB table

Comment: how can i call DAO service in jsp

Comment: Use [JSP Scriptlet tage]
(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html), create a object of your DAO class and call the method on it.

Comment: i am using MVC pattren 
what about JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about how you can pass data between servlet and jsp http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics4.htm#1014110

In your servlet call the dao to fetch the required information. Set the information as request attribute. Use this attribute in jsp to create the drop down.

Other option is using javascript where onload of the html document via ajax you can fetch the data and set in the drop down.

Comment: can anyone provide code to use javascript where onload of the html document via ajax you can fetch the data and set in the drop down.
i am using MVC pattren for jsp
i need it urgent

Comment: Here is an example for you to get started. Its not elegant but at least you will understand how it can be done. http://www.java4s.com/ajax/ajax-jquery-auto-fill-dropdown-on-page-load/